# How to remove eval and Function constructor from webpack build to avoid CSP issues

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webpack, vue.js, firefox-addon

Problem is with Webpack which uses eval in compiled code. Due to this, Chrome extension and Firefox addons does not work as it requires 'unsafe-eval' directive in CSP property which is not allowed. I am using Vue.js for frontend and `webpack` and `vue-loader` for build process

Package.json file

```
{
   "webpack": "^3.10.0",
   "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
   "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
   "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
   "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
   "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
   "vue-loader": "^10.0.2"
}
```

This is what contained within build.js file from webpack. Both Function constructor and eval usages.

```
try {
    // This works if eval is allowed (see CSP)
    g = g || Function("return this")() || (1,eval)("this");
} catch(e) {
    // This works if the window reference is available
    if(typeof window === "object")
        g = window;
}

// Another method of build 
function setImmediate(callback) {
      // Callback can either be a function or a string
      if (typeof callback !== "function") {
        callback = new Function("" + callback);
      }
```

This is the result of the `web-ext` lint which checks for issues in addon

```
Code                    Message          File       Line    Column
DANGEROUS_EVAL          The Function     build.js   433     11
                        constructor is
                        eval.
DANGEROUS_EVAL          eval can be      build.js   433     43
                        harmful.
DANGEROUS_EVAL          The Function     build.js   8814    20
                        constructor is
                        eval.
```

Is there any way I can just build without Webpack using build because from side of Vue there is a support to use runtime code of Vue but Webpack has no flat to build as per CSP policy. Please help as I don't need especially this line in build

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that, Webpack checks for global variables and it needed, `node:false` in Webpack config file which actually removes the above mentioned code. The reason, the above code is not an issue on web application because it won't run the code but in case of Chrome Extension or Firefox plugin, the code is scanned irrespective of execution and this was creating problem.

This is present in webpack source code [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/fb8afe71385734cfd65f47949117306a91f20753/buildin/global.js#L10). More info about globals is present [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx).

Tried it with `webpack: ^3.11.0` version, worked like charm.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because of Vue.js, not Webpack.
According to the [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments):

> Some environments, such as Google Chrome Apps, enforce Content Security Policy (CSP), which prohibits the use of `new Function()` for evaluating expressions. The full build depends on this feature to compile templates, so is unusable in these environments.
>
> On the other hand, the runtime-only build is fully CSP-compliant. When using the runtime-only build with Webpack + vue-loader or Browserify + vueify, your templates will be precompiled into `render` functions which work perfectly in CSP environments.

Unfortunately, Vue doesn't have something like `ng-csp` in Angular. So the only way to run your extension – to use runtime build.

There are good answers how to such build:

- [Vue.js in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615503/vue-js-in-chrome-extension/34621858)
- [Vuejs browser extension without using 'unsafe-eval' in CSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139132/vuejs-browser-extension-without-using-unsafe-eval-in-csp)

Comment: This is not the case, even there is a bug on webpack which does not uses vue.js. I have specially tested that with runtime version of extension and followed every step of Vue to make it CSP compliant. But the issue is with webpack. I am seeking for a config that can solve it or any specific version of webpack that can build CSP compliant code. I have gone through all the lints and para phrase you have mentioned already only after that I have posted this question.
Check this : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5627

Comment: I don't agree. I am not using Vue, but Webpack is generating code which contains calls to eval and to the Function constructor.