# vue cli, production built files but use develop env file

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue 2 to build a firefox extension - the same codebase is also being used to build the chromium extensions.

I want to be able to build using the dev urls.. however when adding the develop flag to vue-cli, the output contains the usual webpack "eval"... which firefox doesn't support in extensions.

How can i use the `.env.development` values while ensuring the code output is no using eval with vue cli?

Related answer (2018)  [How to remove eval and Function constructor from webpack build to avoid CSP issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695579/how-to-remove-eval-and-function-constructor-from-webpack-build-to-avoid-csp-issu#answer-48699215)

Comment: Why not [env.staging](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode)? Does it have to be env.development?

Comment: ah ok.. i didn't know about staging as an inbuilt option will give it a try